# Meaning: in a whirl of excitement

Tags: meaning, collocation

There is a phrase in Daddy-Long-Legs: "in a whirl of excitement". I searched for its meaning but I could not find something precise for that. Please let me know what does exactly that mean?

Answer (score 2):

A Whirl of excitement is an metaphorical phrase used to evoke the imagery of a flurry of activity caused by some stimulus that causes excitement (such as the arrival of a guest).  There is not necessarily a "whirl" (spinning motion), but the language is poetic and evocative.